# JIRA GUI Database Setup

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, jira

I've set up JIRA server 7.6.0 on AWS. Installed MYSQL, PHP support, the Jconnector etc etc.

Connection via chrome is working at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080. I get the JIRA setup page. This is where I am hitting the problem. What do I put in the options?

**Database Type** - MySQL

**Hostname** - ??? (currently I have put in the elastic IP on the AWS box)

**Port** - ??? (currently I'm putting 8080. Not sure if that is right as that is the port for the webserver not the SQL db)

**Database** - ??? (Currently putting "jiradb" but should this be a URL i.e the AWS box url?)

**Username** - jirauser

**Password** - jirapassword

With the settings above I get "error connecting to database". I've copied the j/connector in the lib folder with in the jira home directory.

I've searched high and low on the net and can only find the configuration settings for pointing JIRA to the MySQL server pre first JIRA startup wizard.

Comment: hostname is the adress you type in chrome XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, 8080 is the port. Database is the mysql database name so default is JiraDb. Are you sure about the user/password ? A link that might help : https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/connecting-jira-applications-to-mysql-802592179.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So I hadn't added Security Groups in AWS for port 3306 (the default for MySQL). This has now been added. I now have a different error message which is progress i think!.....

Comment: Edit your question with the error message ;)

Comment: "Error connecting to database.....Connection refused" I'm so close! Anyone?

Comment: as the link above said try this in your mysql :  " SHOW GRANTS FOR <USERNAME>@<JIRA_SERVER_HOSTNAME>; "

Comment: Sorry Daniel. Yeah done all that. Still no joy

Comment: So your user has all the rights ?

Comment: Now i can't even start MySQL. "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"

Comment: So frustrating. Having been on this for three days.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some problem with connection to the MySQL database.

If you are using MySQL on your EC2 instance, not as RDS - you should create an user by yourself.

You can create privileges with following:

```
GRANT ALL ON jira.* TO 'jira_user'@'localhost';
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html